# How to auto refresh remote list, after uploading a local folder to a Storj bucket through FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

In FileZilla client, when a local folder is dragged and dropped into a remote directory, which part of the FileZilla code is recursively sending command to transfer (upload) all local files and sub-folders (within the selected local folder) to the remote end?

My main purpose is to insert command to either list or refresh the remote directory, once the upload is complete. Although this is being done in ftp and sftp protocols, but I am not able to do so for [storj](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/trunk/src/storj/) feature.

I have tried the including the "list" or refersh commands at the following points in different codes:

1. at the end of the "put" command within /src/storj/fzstorj.cpp file
2. after the "Transfers finished" notification in `void CQueueView::ActionAfter(bool warned)` function in /src/interface/QueueView.cpp file
   Reason: this notification is displayed when all files and subfolders of a selected local folder have been uploaded to a Storj bucket.
3. I also tried tracking files that take part in the process, mainly those within /src/engine/storj folder, like, file_transfer.cpp sending "put" command through `int CStorjFileTransferOpData::Send()`function
   This did not help much.
4. While checking who is giving command to the storj engine, I observed it is being done by calling `void CCommandQueue::ProcessCommand(CCommand *pCommand, CCommandQueue::command_origin origin)` in /src/interface/commandqueue.cpp

Expected output is autorefreshing of Storj bucket or upload path, when all desired files and sub-folders are uploaded from the local end through FileZilla client.

Any hint towards the solution would be of great help to me.

Thank You!

Comment: Once it is know, my plan is to call ```CListCommand``` as done in ```bool CRemoteRecursiveOperation::NextOperation()``` within the /src/interface/remote_recursive_operation.cpp file.

Comment: That is a question you better ask at FileZilla forum.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the pointer! Yet, the FZ forum is 'blocked' from my end. In any case, I have queried it at their IRC #FileZilla group.